# Offline Video Subtitle creator for Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, closed-captions

I'm looking for a **free offline Subtitle creator** program that allows me to create & edit subtitles for my screen recorded videos from scratch. Any suggestions of a product that's free (like in "free beer"), offline & good quality for Windows? Formats `.srt` and `.sub` should be supported at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

### Hard Subtitles

These are visible all of the time on the final video.

There are a few dependencies to install but [MoviePy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) fits the bill neatly. You can even do the [Star Wars titles effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=5euLdo8L0o0) or [Moving Letters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=jj5qrHl5ZS0).

1. Subtitle Videos **Yes** see method [here](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videotools.html#module-moviepy.video.tools.subtitles). The format of the subtitles file (.srt) is [SubRip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip) format.
2. Produce good quality output **Yes** Uses [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) for the video processing which supports a large number of video formats.
3. Free, Gratis & Open Source **Yes** All of the tools involved are as well
4. Windows **Yes** Cross platform so OS-X and Linux also.

Dependencies:

- [Python](https://www.python.org)
- [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/)
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) - For windows see the note [here](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html#other-optional-but-useful-dependencies).
- [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/)
- [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml), [SciPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) & [SciKit-Image](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-image) - Be sure to install the builds that match the version of python you installed.
- Python Packages Pillow, SciPy & - Once python is installed `pip install -U Pillow`

### Soft Subtitles

The viewer can select whether to see the subtitles or not.
Probably your best choice is [SubtitleEdit](http://nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit/).

- Good Quality **Yes**
- Free, Gratis & Open Source **Yes**
- Windows **Yes**
- Supports over 200 formats

Comment: enjoying SubtitleEdit.  Took just a little bit to get into it.  The documentation is thin, but open the Settings and you can see what to do...  especially see the "Shortcuts" tab for finding and setting up the controls you need.

Answer (score 2):

From my perspective, efficient subtitle editing takes the advantage of visualizing the audio track. According to this criteria, here are two powerful tools that fits this criteria:

- **[Aigesub](http://www.aegisub.org/)** is a great option, not only it is equipped with the visualization of audio track, but it also has live preview, and the visual style editor. According to my knowledge, many Chinese subtitle group is currently using this one as a workhorse tool.
- **[Arctime](http://www.arctime.org/)** is a software currently under active development, it support drag and drop, and has a beautiful user interface.

Both of these two software can be used on several platforms.